# Rewriting an ugly function

Tags: python

I have been recommended on stack to rewrite the function, but it does get the job done. Can I improve the efficiency or readability?

```
def get_notifyees(jobdef):
    if 'notifyees' in jobdef:
        origNotifyeesList = jobdef['notifyees'] if isinstance(jobdef['notifyees'], list) \
        or jobdef['notifyees'] is None else [jobdef['notifyees']]

        origNotifyeesList = origNotifyeesList if origNotifyeesList is not None else []
    notifyeesList = []
    for notifyee in origNotifyeesList:
        if 'noreply' not in notifyee:
            notifyeesList.append(notifyee)
    return notifyeesList
```

Comment: We're all here to receive constructive criticism of our code. Please try to include a title that describes what your code *does*.

Comment: Hello,
Would you be able to tell us more about the intent of the function ? An exemple would be welcome.

Answer (score 5):

**General comment**

Your code does not seem properly tested. If the first test were to return `false`, you'd get the following error :

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'origNotifyeesList' referenced before assignment`

**Don't repeat yourself**

You are repeting the same thing a lot making the code hard to read. You could store `jobdef['notifyees']` in a variable.

```
    notif = jobdef['notifyees']
    origNotifyeesList = notif if isinstance(notif, list) \
    or notif is None else [notif]
```

**List comprehension**

You can rewrite the end of your code with a single list comprehension : `return [notifyee for notifyee in origNotifyeesList if 'noreply' not in notifyee]` .

Comment: Would you keep if statement though. and initialization of the list notifyeesList

Answer (score 1):

The root of the ugliness is the inconsistently structured data you are dealing with. I suggest using a separate function to ensure that you are always dealing with a list. You can reuse the function wherever you have the same problem. The function does not have to be uglier than this:

```
def listify(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return x
    elif x is None:
        return []
    else:
        return [x]
```

Your function can then be rewritten like this. I'm using `jobdef.get` assuming you want to end up with an empty list when the key is missing from the dict, and Josay's list comprehension:

```
def get_notifyees(jobdef):
    origNotifyeesList = listify(jobdef.get('notifyees'))
    return [notifyee for notifyee in origNotifyeesList 
            if 'noreply' not in notifyee]
```

Comment: what does listify mean?  I get the function, just trying to understand the naming.

Comment: "to make something a list", see http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-fy